# Why SqlBulkCopy gets slower by table's row count?

Tags: sql-server, bulk-insert

I'm using SqlBulkCopy to insert a lot of data (10000/second at peek) into a database. And when the table starts empty, each bulk insertion takes like 300 milliseconds. But after a day when the records count become more than 20 millions, the insertion time becomes 2.5 seconds per 10K records. And this time increases with the count of records.

I have only a simple table, with no indexes except an identity clustered primary key.

I thought that this behavior is an append-only behavior and won't be affected by the table size. Like throwing a pile of litter on yet a huge pile of litter. That shouldn't be affected by the size.

What do I miss here?

**Update:** Table's script created via SSMS is:

```
CREATE TABLE [pardis].[DeliveryReports](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PardisId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PartId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ShortCode] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [DateTimeReceived] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PersianDateTimeReceived] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [DateTimeSentToCp] [datetime] NULL,
    [PersianDateTimeSentToCp] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [DeliveringToCpResult] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsProcessing] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_DeliveryReports_IsProcessing_1]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [IsSentToCp] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_DeliveryReports_IsSentToCp]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DeliveryReports] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

**Update 2:** This is the execution plan for inserting 1 record via SSMS. As you can see, no hidden cost exists in inserting records in the table. **Please note that this execution plan is after deleting the primary key index to prevent any index from affecting the performance.**

[image]

Comment: Provide the execution plan. Probably, there is a non-append-only component to the inserts. Maybe an index that causes randomly placed writes. Eventually, the buffer pool cannot buffer those write anymore and performance tanks big time. Append-only inserts never get slower over time.

Comment: @usr, I checked the execution plan for 1 record, and it seems that no hidden cost exists. I don't know how to see the execution plan of bulk insert though.

Comment: Two more ideas: Auto-grow and changing size of rows being inserted (becoming bigger). You need to investigate that.

Comment: You can capture the bulk plan using SQL Profiler and the Showplan XML event. But it will be just as boring. The 1 row plan is sufficient here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why you write that you don't make any index ?
What is PK_DeliveryReports in your opinion ? 
As for me - the clu of your problem is just rebuilding of PK.
Try to use partitions to your table - or drop this index (PK) and rebuild it after the load - should be quicker (of course if you don't need index during the load for other purposes).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I removed primary key index altogether, but no change. I think something else might be the cause.